# Save and reuse jQuery tabs sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui

I'm trying to save the sort order of the jQuery tabs after an end user changes then and then save them to local storage so that I can reorder the tabs on the next visit.

Currently I'm storing the id's of the tabs by looping the elements however I came across a jQuery method that should do it automatically

https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

```
     var sorted = $( ".selector" ).sortable( "serialize", { key: "sort" } );

      var sortedIDs = $( ".selector" ).sortable( "toArray" );
```

my problem either way is how do I use the new tab order?  Do I have to create a function that loops and inserts before or after? or is there a method the takes the saved sorted value?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you might find it easier to just store the resulting html in a variable:

```js
 var sorter = $("#sortable");

 var goSort = function() {
   sorter.sortable();
   sorter.disableSelection();
 };
 goSort();

 var starter = sorter.html();
 var storeroom = starter;

 $('.start').on({
   mouseup: function() {
     sorter.html(starter);
     goSort();
   }
 });

 $('.recent').on({
   mouseup: function() {
     sorter.html(storeroom);
     goSort();
   }
 });

 $('.record').on({
   mouseup: function() {
     storeroom = sorter.html();
   }
 });
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}
#sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
#sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
.record,
.start,
.recent {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #09f;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>

<div class="start">start</div>
<div class="record">record</div>
<div class="recent">restore</div>
```

Comment: interesting- I might consider that- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did end up with doing:

```
    function reorderTabs() {
            var ul = document.getElementById("menu");

            var tabList = tabsArray.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
                var el = tabList[i];
                var li = document.getElementById(el);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
```